# Wrong size of PlayerView inside NestedScrollView with wrap_content width

Tags: exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

When `PlayerView` is inside `FrameLayout`, it is correctly scaled to the video size:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/playerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

However, after replacing layout with `NestedScrollView`, it seems like the view takes only controls height when calculating height of the `PlayerView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/playerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to add the following parameter to `PlayerView`:

```
app:resize_mode="fixed_width"
```